# Proof that $f(t) P(x; \sigma = 1)$ is equivilant to $P(x; \sigma = f(t))$ where $P(x; \sigma)$ is a PDF with a single mode

Tags: distributions, residuals, rayleigh-distribution

Consider some function or lineshape, $f(t)$, whose form is known. Also consider some one-parameter PDF, $P(x;\sigma)$ where $\sigma$ is a shape parameter -- and importantly defines the mode of $P(x;\sigma)$.

Now consider the following case. I now measure some data as a function of $t$ and I know that each measured point is sampled from the PDF $P(x;\sigma)$, except now the shape parameter, $\sigma$ is defined by $f(t)$. Such that
$$P(x;\sigma = f(t))$$
That is, for every value of $t$ I measure my data, I am measuring a data point which is drawn from the PDF $P(x;\sigma)$, but with a different shape parameter each time as $\sigma = f(t)$.So I have some measured data
$$F(t)\sim P(x;\sigma = f(t))$$

If I now take the log of both my measured data and function, and subtract them
$$R_{\rm{log}} = \log_{10}(F) - \log_{10}(f(t))$$
i.e. looking at the residuals, and converting back into a linear scale,
$R_{\rm{lin}} = 10^{R_{\rm{log}}}$, I find that the distribution of my residuals follow the distribution
$$P(x;\sigma = 1)$$

**How can I prove this mathematically?**

I'll show my scenario with some simulation. It is written in Mathematica but hopefully the code is
fairly readable.

```
f[A_, w0_, t_] := A * Sin[w0 * t] + 2 * A
```

I then generate my un-noised pure "fit function". I chose `A = 1`, `w0 = 0.1`

```
UnnoisedData =  Table[Log10[f[1, 0.1, t]], {t, 0 , 10, 10^-3}];
```

This generates the noised data from `t = 0` to `t = 10` in a step size of `10^-3`. I now generate the noised data as

```
NoisedData = Table[Log10[RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[f[1, 0.1, t]]]], {t, 0 , 100, 10^-3}];
```

Here I have chosen the Rayleigh distribution and in Mathematica, the function `RayleighDistribution[s]` takes one argument `s` which is the shape parameter I described above. Notice in both cases I have already taken the logarithm to the base 10.

I know generate my residuals

```
Rlog = NoisedData - UnnoisedData;
Rlin = 10^Rlog;
```

If I look at the histogram of my residuals $Rlin$ I see

[image]

So my residual in linear units follow a perfect Rayeligh distribution with a shaoe parameter $\sigma = 1$. I have confirmed this with large numbers of simulations. This example has $100,001$ data points, and perfomred Maximum Likelihood evaluations to confirm the shape parameter.

---

**Some additional comments**

Thinking about the problem a little more, I suppose what it comes down to is how the following expressions are related:
$$f(t) P(x;\sigma = 1)$$
and
$$P(x; \sigma = f(t))$$
because if we consider $\sigma$ to be the mode of the PDF $P(x; \sigma)$, then the two expressions above must be somehow equivalent.

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3753731/321264.